# Sudden Death Mode

Tags: puzzle-strike

When playing Puzzle Strike [online](http://www.fantasy-strike.com), my friends and I encountered a sort of "Sudden Death" mode that activated after many turns of a particularly slow game, resulting in 2-Gems being anted each turn instead of 1-Gems.  We could not figure out exactly what the trigger of this was - likely some specific number of turns - or whether or not this rule was supposed to be used in the physical version.  I do not believe the rule exists in the Version 1 Rulebook.  **What is the trigger of this Sudden Death mode that increases the ante, and is it universal to all versions of the game?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The online version uses the [3rd edition rules](http://www.sirlin.net/ps/rules) which state

> In a 2-player game, the ﬁrst moment there are two  simultaneously
>   empty stacks in the bank, Panic Time is  activated and everyone must
>   ante 2-gems from then on.  Even if chips later return to bank and ﬁll
>   up some stacks,  the game does not return to Normal Time. The ﬁrst 
>   moment there are three simultaneously empty bank  stacks, Danger Time
>   is activated and everyone antes 3- gems from then on. The ﬁrst time
>   four stacks are  simultaneously empty, Deadly Time is activated and 
>   everyone must ante 4-gems from then on. Note that if  you would ever
>   ante a certain kind of gem that the bank  is out of, you must ante it
>   anyway with a stand-in gem of  some sort.
>
> For games with 3 or 4 players, the same sort of thing  happens. The
>   number of empty stacks needed to activate  Panic Time is actually X,
>   where X is the number of players. X+1, and X+2 empty stacks are when
>   Danger Time and Deadly Time  activate. The 2 vs. 2 Team Battle mode
>   counts as 4-player game for purposes of the Panic Time rules.